# Incrementing variable on sensor event change

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've got this snippet of code here, and in my head I made it to set the caloriestext string to what ever cCounter is and cCounter is a string that gets it's text from an integer called cburn. The problem is when I run the app, the caloriestext is set to 0.0 and does not update.

I know this probably seems rudimentary, but I've been trying to get it to work all week and have had no luck. Thanks much for any help you can provide.

```java
package shake.shake;

/**
 * Created by ink on 3/24/16.
 */
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class main extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    private float mLastX, mLastY, mLastZ;
    private boolean mInitialized;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;

    private final float NOISE = (float) 3.3;


    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mInitialized = false;
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        Context context = this;

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.app_soundtrack);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);

        Context context = this;
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.app_soundtrack);
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
// can be safely ignored for this demo
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // Load the ImageView that will host the animation and
        // set its background to our AnimationDrawable XML resource.
        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.shake1);
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shake_animation);

        // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

        // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
        frameAnimation.start();

        TextView tvX= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.x_axis);
        TextView tvY= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.y_axis);
        TextView tvZ= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.z_axis);
        TextView cCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.caloriestext);
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];

        if (!mInitialized) {
            mLastX = x;
            mLastY = y;
            mLastZ = z;
            tvX.setText("0.0");
            tvY.setText("0.0");
            tvZ.setText("0.0");
            cCounter.setText("0");
            mInitialized = true;
        } else {
            float deltaX = Math.abs(mLastX - x);
            float deltaY = Math.abs(mLastY - y);
            float deltaZ = Math.abs(mLastZ - z);
            if (deltaX < NOISE) deltaX = (float)0.0;
            if (deltaY < NOISE) deltaY = (float)0.0;
            if (deltaZ < NOISE) deltaZ = (float)0.0;
            mLastX = x;
            mLastY = y;
            mLastZ = z;
            int cburn = 0;
            tvX.setText(Float.toString(deltaX));
            tvY.setText(Float.toString(deltaY));
            tvZ.setText(Float.toString(deltaZ));
            cCounter.setText(Float.toString(cburn));
            if (deltaX > deltaY) {
                frameAnimation.start();
                cburn++;
            } else if (deltaY > deltaX) {
                frameAnimation.start();
                cburn++;
            } else {
                frameAnimation.stop();
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

I don't think it's that important, but here's the corresponding .xml file

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="243dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:id="@+id/caloriestext"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Calories:"
        android:textSize="20pt"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_column="12"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="12pt"
        android:id="@+id/calories"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shake1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/shake1"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/y_axis"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="1pt"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/z_axis"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="1pt"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/x_axis"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="1pt"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you make height of `y_axis` `match_parent`, other TextViews won't be visible on the screen. You should make them `wrap_content`.

Your `cCounter` TextView stays `0.0` because you create `cburn` variable inside of `onSensorChanged` method. Every time the method gets called, `cburn` variable is created again and assigned `0` value. You need to make `cburn` global. Move this line:

```
int cburn = 0;
```

here:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    ...
    int cburn = 0;
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't the cburn++ in the if and else if statements change it?

Comment: oh, it does! but you create cburn inside of the `onSensorChanged` method. move this line `int cburn = 0;` right under `private Sensor mAccelerometer;` I'm updating my answer!